# Android react-native ignore or obey system autorotation settings toggle lock

Tags: android, react-native

Q0: If I want to ignore system autorotation settings toggle lock in Android and autorotate even if the user has locked the orientation, how would I do it?

Q1: If my app is ignoring the system autorotation settings toggle lock in Android and autorotating even though the system specifies to lock the orientation, how do I make it obey the lock?

Answer (score 0):

A0: In `AndroidManifest.xml`, set `android:screenOrientation="sensor"` and rebuild.

A1: In `AndroidManifest.xml`, set `android:screenOrientation="unspecified"` and rebuild.